# Adjusting the limits of x and y axis, when adding new curves to a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, range

I have two datasets (`df1` and `df2`) that are plotted.

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c(1:10), y=c(1:10))
df2 = data.frame(x=c(0:13), y=c(0:13)^1.2)

# plot
plot(df1)
# add lines of another dataset
lines(df2)
```

Some values of `df2` are out of the plot-range and thus not visible. (In this example I could just plot `df2` first). I usually try to find out the ranges of my data, as shown below.

```
# manual solution
minX = min(df1$x, df2$x)
minY = min(df1$y, df2$y)
maxX = max(df1$x, df2$x)
maxY = max(df1$y, df2$y)

plot (df1, xlim=c(minX, maxX), ylim=c(minY, maxY))
lines(df2)
```

When having many datasets, this becomes annoying. I was wondering, if there is an easier way of adjusting the ranges of the axis.
In the first step R finds axis ranges itself. Is there also a way that R adjusts the axis-ranges, when new datasets are added?

Comment: Merge the `data.frames`, create a group variable, use `ggplot2`.

Comment: @Roland: I don't see hoew merging dataframes of different length solves the problem. What is a group variable? How would the solution be in ggplot2 (I never used it before)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `range` to calculate the limits.

Imho, a better solution:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:10), y=c(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(0:13), y=c(0:13)^1.2)

ll <- list(df1,df2)

ll <- lapply(1:length(ll),function(i) {res <- ll[[i]]; res$grp <- i; res})

df <- do.call("rbind",ll)
df$grp <- factor(df$grp)

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,group=grp,col=grp)) + geom_line()
p1
```

Answer (score 3):

I like @Roland's solution, but here is an extension of @Glen_b's solution that works for an arbitrary number of data sets, *if* you have them all in a list.

(*warning*: untested!)

```
dflist <- list(df1,df2,df3,...)  ## dots are not literal!
plotline <- function(L,...) {    ## here the dots are literal
  ## use them to specify (e.g.) xlab, ylab, other arguments to plot()
  allX <- unlist(lapply(L,"[[","x"))
  allY <- unlist(lapply(L,"[[","y"))
  plot (df1, xlim=range(allX), ylim=range(allY),type="n",...)
  invisible(lapply(L,lines))
}
```

This assumes that you want all the data sets drawn as lines.
If you want to start specify separate colours, point types, etc., you could extend this function -- but you would be starting to re-invent the `lattice` and `ggplot2` packages at that point.

(If all your data sets are the same size, you should consider `matplot`)

Answer (score 2):

You could always write a function:

```
plotline <- function(df1,df2) {

  minX = min(df1$x, df2$x)
  minY = min(df1$y, df2$y)
  maxX = max(df1$x, df2$x)
  maxY = max(df1$y, df2$y)

  plot (df1, xlim=c(minX, maxX), ylim=c(minY, maxY))
  lines(df2)
}
```

Then you just do this:

```
plotline(firstdf,seconddf)
```

If you want to get fancy, you can even include the argument `...` and pass it to the plot call.

Comment: I sometimes have 20 datasets in one plot, so the `plotline`-function wouldn't work. What is the `...` argument used for in plot? or did you mean the the own plotline-function?

Comment: It's easy to modify the function to take a subset of columns from a dataframe, or a list of dataframes, or a matrix, or any of several other ways of specifying a bunch of things to plot. As for the `...` argument, it's a way of passing additional arguments down to things your function calls (in this case, to plot, so plotline would allow you to set any of the things that plot lets you set). See section 10.4 of "An Introduction to R".

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `matplot` function, it will accept a matrix as x, y, or both and do all the automatic range calculations for you.  If you have the data in multiple data frames then you can use sapply to extract the key pieces and form the matricies.

This approach is often even simpler than using the lines function multiple times:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(x=0:13, y=(0:13)^1.2)
df3 <- data.frame(x= -3:5, y= 5:(-3))

mylist <- list( df1, df2, df3 )
max.n <- max(sapply(mylist,nrow))
tmpfun <- function(df, which.col, n) {
    tmp <- df[[which.col]]
    c(tmp, rep(NA, n-length(tmp)))
}

matplot( sapply(mylist, tmpfun, which.col='x', n=max.n),
        sapply(mylist, tmpfun, which.col='y', n=max.n), type='b' )
```

The above is even simpler if all the data frames have the same number of rows.

The other approach as mentioned in the comments is to combine the datasets into a single dataset and use tools like lattice graphics or ggplot2:

```
lengths <- sapply(mylist, nrow)
df.all <- do.call(rbind, mylist)
df.all$group <- rep( seq_along(lengths), lengths )

library(lattice)
xyplot( y~x, data=df.all, groups=group, type='b' )

library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,y, colour=factor(group), data=df.all, geom=c('point','path') )
```

If all else fails you can use the `zoomplot` function from the TeachingDemos package to change the limits of base graphics after the fact, but the above methods are much better.